# Algebraic relation amongst an elliptic function and its convolution

Tags: convolution, elliptic-functions, algebraic-equations

### NOTE: I edited this question, following the comments of Alexander Eremenko and Paul Garrett.

I have a question concerning elliptic functions that maybe you can help me shed light on. I am a theoretical physicist so I excuse myself preemptively for any mathematical imprecision.

It is a fact that any two elliptic functions $f(z)$ and $g(z)$, having the same periodicities, satisfy an algebraic relation $$F[f,g]=0\;,$$ where $F$ is a polynomial in two variables with constant coefficients.

Similarly, it is a fact that, given an elliptic function $f(z)$, its convolution with another generic function $h(z)$ is again an elliptic function, having the same periodicities: $$c(z) = \intop_{-\infty}^{\infty} dw\,f(z-w)h(w)\;,$$ $$\left\lbrace\begin{array}{c} f(z+\omega_1) = f(z) \\ f(z+\omega_3) = f(z)\end{array}\right.\quad \Longrightarrow \quad \left\lbrace\begin{array}{c} c(z+\omega_1) = c(z) \\ c(z+\omega_3) = c(z)\end{array}\right.\;.$$ The function $h(z)$ is such that the convolution is well-defined.

Given the two facts above, I deduce that there exist an algebraic relation of the form $$\mathcal{F}[f,c] = \sum_{n=0}^N\sum_{m=0}^M \alpha_{n,m} f(z)^n\,c(z)^m = 0\;.$$

---

EDITS

As it was remarked in the comments, the above statement is, in general, not true. In fact, let $\omega_1$ and $\omega_3$ be the two periods of the elliptic function $f(z)$. Suppose moreover that $\omega_1\in\mathbb R_{>0}$ and $-i\omega_3\in\mathbb R_{>0}$ (Note that I use $\omega_{1,3}$ for the entire periods, not the half-ones as is customary). Let moreover be $\lbrace \zeta_k\rbrace$ be the poles of $f(z)$ in the fundamental rectangle with vertices $0$, $\omega_1$, $\omega_3$ and $\omega_1+\omega_3$. Finally, suppose that $-i\omega_3>\Im\zeta_k>0,\;\forall k$, so that the convolution is well-defined (also, $h(z)$ has no poles on the real axis). Then it seems to me quite evident that the convolution $c(z)$ is periodic with period $\omega_1$, since any performed change of integration variable would not move the integration contour. In formulae \begin{eqnarray*}c(z) &= \intop_{-\infty}^{\infty} dw\, f(w)h(z-w) = \intop_{-\infty}^{\infty} dw\, f(w-\omega_1)h((z+\omega_1)-w) =\\ &= \intop_{-\infty}^{\infty} dw\, f(w)h((z+\omega_1)-w) = c(z+\omega_1)\;. \end{eqnarray*}

On the other hand, the periodicity $z\rightarrow z+\omega_3$ is in general violated. In fact, the convolution will be multi-valued, as Alexander pointed out. We can say that $$ c(z) = \intop_{-\infty}^{\infty} dw\, f(z-w)h(w) = \intop_{-\infty}^{\infty} dw\, f(z-w+\omega_3)h(w) = c(z+\omega_3)\;,$$ owing to the periodicity of $f$. However we might as well compute as follows \begin{eqnarray*} c(z) &=& \intop_{-\infty}^{\infty} dw\, f(w)h(z-w) = \intop_{-\omega_3-\infty}^{-\omega_3+\infty} dw\, f(w)h(z-w) - 2\pi i\sum \textrm{Res}_{\zeta_k} = \\ &=& \intop_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dw\, f(w-\omega_3)h((z+\omega_3)-w) - 2\pi i\sum \textrm{Res}_{\zeta_k} = c(z+\omega_3) - 2\pi i\sum \textrm{Res}_{\zeta_k}\;. \end{eqnarray*} Here I denote schematically by $\sum \textrm{Res}_{\zeta_k}$ the sum over all the residues picked up by the shift in the integration contour.

As an example, I computed numerically $c(z)$ for $f(z) = \textrm{cn}_l(z)$ and $h(z) = e^{-z^2}$, verifying the $\omega_1$ periodicity. For the $\omega_3$ lack of periodicity, I see that the two definitions of the convolution yield different numerical results, but I cannot match the difference with the residues (I probably am counting them wrong).

So, given the above, I guess that my question below concerns a specific case in which $h(z)$ is periodic of period $\omega_3$. For example, the case $f(z) = \textrm{cn}_l(z)$ and $h(z) = \frac{1}{\cosh(\frac{\pi}{2K_{1-l}}z)}$, where $\omega_3 = 2i K_{1-l}$. For this situation, the convolution should be doubly periodic and my question should make sense.

I tried the example I mentioned and I verified that both definitions of the convolution (with $w-z$ in $f$ or $g$) yield the same result when shifted by the periods. Again I could not verify the nullity of the sum of residues, probably because I am doing something wrong.

To answer the latest comments: what I mean by convolution is a 1-dimensional integral over the real numbers.

---

QUESTION

My question is the following: is there a simple (or at the very least, feasible) way to find the integers $N$ and $M$ and, possibly, compute the coefficients $\alpha_{n,m}$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: With convolution, it is problematic. Elliptic function has poles. If you integrate on the real line, and there happens to be a pole on your way, the integral will diverge. Anyway, you want your "convolution" to be defined for complex arguments, and it will not be a function since it will be multivalued. So is is not correct to say that "convolution of an elliptic function with anything is elliptic". Also, in your last eq. you have c in the LHS and g in the RHS. This must be a misprint.

Comment: Yes, although the general idea makes some sense, the biggest obstacle, as @AlexandreEremenko comments, is the meaning of convolution when applied to a meromorphic function. E.g., even heuristically, does it smear out poles? What would that mean? (Saying "principal value" does not seem to be enough?) E.g., elliptic functions with double poles are not locally $L^1$... Clarify?

Comment: On the other hand, answering the question about $M,N$ in the last (corrected) formula is easy, if one knows that  $f,c$ are both elliptic.

Comment: @paul garrett: when you go around a pole, something is added (the residue) so a convolution is not a single-valued function. It can be elliptic (single valued) only under very special conditions on $f$ and $g$.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko, I'm a little confused: _if_ I construe "convolution" as the obvious real-two-dimensional integral, at a simple pole for example (so, locally integrable), I don't see how to get extra things to prevent double periodicity of the convolution. After all, the whole set-up could be construed as concerning (complex-valued) functions on a two-torus $\mathbb T^2$, no?

Comment: It is a general fact that if $f,g$ are two rational functions on an algebraic curve, with minimal polynomial $P(f,g)=0$, then the degree of $P$ with respect to $f$ (resp. $g$) is less than or equal to the degree of $g$ (resp. $f$), with equality if $f,g$ generate the function field.

Comment: @paul garrett: what OP wrote is a 1-dimensonal integral:-) 2 dimensional of a doubly periodic function will be divergent. So it is not clear what the question means.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko, ah, indeed. Unclear. Probably the intent/context is also unclear for the asker. Unless I am mistaken, a doubly-periodic function with simple poles _is_ locally $L^1$, so an integral on a (real-) two-torus would have a sense. But certainly not for general elliptic functions. Hard to guess the intent...

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: and to Paul too, I edited the question following your comments. I was cavalier by not considering the effect of complex poles when defining the periodicity. So the context of my question is reduced to the case in which $h(z)$ is periodic with an imaginary period $\omega_3$ and $f(z)$ is elliptic with periods $\omega_1$ (real) and $\omega_3$.